# Какое правило регулирует -шний/-шный в конце прилагательных?

Tags: суффиксы-прилагательных

*кромешный, 
всамделишный / невсамделишный, 
взбалмошный,
доминошный,
лотошный,
никчемушный,
никудышный,
синюшный,
зряшный*

и ещё [вереница](http://slovar.cc/ses/orujie/2504779.html) (не очень длинная)...

Comment: Вопрос в том, от чего зависит, Ы там или И?

Comment: Угу. "11 символов нужно..." )))

Comment: Что?! Мы рассматриваем слова только от 11 знаков, или как?

Comment: Не-а. Это я пыталась отделаться угумом, а мне возразили нехваткой знаков. )))

Comment: Ну у вас тут вообще солянка сборная. В половине случаев Ш - корневое. Вообще непонятно, что оно тут делает...

Comment: Без этого Ш корневого и вопрос не состоялся бы. Вот Серж и ответил без Ш корневого... А почему солянка-то? Куча примеров приведена. Всегдашний или всегдашный? По словарю немудрено проверить, но я надеялась на некую закономерность, отображённую правилом.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Чаще всего  суфф. -ШН- присоединяется к неизменяемым словам на гласный:

кроме/шн/ый, домино/шн/ый, лото/шн/ый, никчему/шн/ый, никуды/шн/ый, всамдели/шн/ый / невсамдели/шн/ый ("в самом деле" как фразеологизм), зря/шн/ый, ПОЗАВЧЕРА/ШН/ИЙ, ТОГДА/ШН/ИЙ, ДОМА/ШН/ИЙ (от наречия "дома"), ТАМО/ШН/НИЙ ("тамо" - так выглядело наречие "там"),

взбалмошный (от взбаламученный-баламучный; чн-шн),

По Вашей ссылке в основном чередования согл. в корне. 
Часты **чередования х//ш в корне перед** суфф. -Н-: синюшный (синюха -  синюшный)
соха - ЧЕРНОСОШНЫЙ, утеха - УТЕШНЫЙ, успех - УСПЕШНЫЙ, дух - ТЩЕДУШНЫЙ, СЛАБОДУШНЫЙ,  суматоха - СУМАТОШНЫЙ, пахать - СТАРОЗАПАШНЫЙ, спех - СПЕШНЫЙ, СКОРОСПЕШНЫЙ,соха - СОШНЫЙ, скоморох - СКОМОРОШНЫЙ, рюха - РЮШНЫЙ

с//ш весна-ВЕШНИЙ

**Когда  -ый-, когда -ИЙ?** Как выбрать между мягким и твёрдым согласным?

**Финали -н(ий) и -шн(ий) используются в относительных прилагательных с временным и пространственным значением, а финали -н(ый) и -шн(ый) – в прилагательных, не имеющих такого значения.**

Например: послезавтрашний, внешний, нынешний, вчерашний, тогдашний, осенний, новогодний, вечерний, задний, летний, крайний, передний, верхний, иногородний. Исключение ПРИГОРОДНЫЙ.

НО: доминошный, киношный, зряшный, арбузный, винный, медный,
шоколадный, хвойный, янтарный, барабанный, ватный, карандашный.

К сожалению, никаких ссылок дать не могу. Если не верите, попробуйте опровергнуть.

Comment: "Финали -н(ий) и -шн(ий) используются в относительных прилагательных с **временным** и **пространственным** значением, а финали -н(ый) и -шн(ый) – в прилагательных, не имеющих такого значения". Дело в том, что я тоже искал закономерность, когда Галина задала вопрос, и тоже предположил именно пространственное и временное значение у слов со ШНИЙ, но потом нашёл слова без этого значения: (из)лишний и взаправдашний.

Comment: Людмила, Вы серьезно думаете, что эти правила помогут человеку, который не понимает разницы между твердым и мягким согласным?  ))) Тем более, что куча исключений. Наверняка, это лишь малая толика от реального их количества. *Дэти, слова*  *вилька, тарелька и бутылька пишутся без мягкого знака. А сол,*  *фасол и  вермишел - с мягким. Это невозможно понять, это надо* *запомнить*.(С)

Comment: Бегемотчина! Вы почти что Мужчина! "Есть всё, но без пяти минут". (С)

Answer (score 1):

Выбор окончания в этом случае зависит от двух факторов: в безударном положении на мягкую основу пишем ***ий***, на  твердую -   ***ый***.  ***Ой*** пишется перед твердым согласным под ударением.

Ср.: жи[**в**]-ой, но[**в**]-ый; зим[***н'***]-ий; упру[***г'***]-ий; мел[***к'***]-ий; су[***х***]-ой; горя[***ч'***]-ий; боль[***ш***]-ой.

Comment: Серж, не поняла. Во-первых, не насчитала двух факторов (ударение и мягкость/твёрдость?); во-вторых, коль речь об окончании, то, должно быть не "перед", а "после" согласного? И в-третьих, вопрос не о любых окончаниях прилагательных, а оканчивающихся на -шний/-шный. Например, "всегдашный" или "всегдашний" - как определять?

Comment: Галина, два фактора - это ударение, твердость и мягкость. Про шний/-шный в справочниках ничего не говорится. В этих случаях надо ориентироваться на словарь. В любом случае - поищу! Если найду - напишу.

Comment: Сержик, поищите - это интересно! Людмила исходит из своего опыта и говорит, что ссылок дать не может... Бросает нам вызов: "Если не верите, попробуйте опровергнуть"!

Comment: Галина, суффикс н- (-шн-)  обозначает прилагательное со значением  признака или свойства, относящегося к предмету, явлению, действию, месту, времени или числу, названному исходным словом (весенний, дальний, вчерашний, домашний, тысячный);
• подверженности какому-нибудь действию или результата какого-либо действия, которое названо исходным словом (отглагольные прилагательные ) ( рваный, читаный, званый, драный).[Суффиксы прилагат-ых](http://ok.ru/dk?cmd=logExternal&st._aid=Conversations_Openlink&st.name=externalLinkRedirect&st.link=http%3A%2F%2Fwordsland.ru%2Fmagiclanguage%2Fsuff.html%23prilag)

Comment: Галина, как видите, Людмила права. Шн - суффикс, а ый/ий зависит от твердости- мягкости.

Answer (score 1):

сегодн'jа - гласная "мягкого ряда" (которая смягчает предыдущую согласную, превращая ее в палатализованную), это интересный случай, когда смягчение переносится вперёд на новый суффикс и далее на окончание - сегодняшний

успех - основа оканчивается на твердую согласную х - и этот эффект переносится вперёд на словобразовательный суффикс и далее на окончание (или можно сказать, что палатализации не происходит) - успешный

Таким образом, надо искать основу слова и исходить из этого. Иногда эти основы уже утеряны в языке (архаичные слова), поэтому некоторые случаи трудно бывает объяснить.

Comment: Спасибо. Ответ Людмилы - исчерпывающий.

Answer (score 0):

Galina Avanesova, можно в лоб вопрос? У вас русский - родной?

-ий/-ый пишется в прилагательных **в полном соответствии с произношением.**
Я просто затрудняюсь дать какое-то ещё правило. Да, иностранцам бывает тяжело, приходится запоминать...
Но вон даже Серж, хоть и запутал в трех соснах, но "правило" дал. Как слышится, так и пишется. 
Что там перед окончанием стоит - ШН или еще чего - дело д5есятое. Если последний согласный твердый, значит ЫЙ. Если мягкий - ИЙ.
Неужели не слышите разницу? Ну поставьте в женский род. Там к вас ЯЯ/АЯ не путается? Если путается, то только словарь - и учить.

(+)

Наверное есть какое-то статистическое правило, что мягкость наследуется от основы (даль-дальний, зал-зальный), но вы замучаетесь основы вычленять, если уж ухо не подсказывает.

Comment: Разумеется, Галина знает, как пишутся и звучат эти слова. Как я понял, она просто хочет понять закономерность, которая определяет гласную в окончании. Это действительно интересно понять.

Comment: Бегемотик, роднее не бывает. Причём московский русский. Вы в мой профиль не заглядывали? Я корректор и редактор. Спец по русскому. Но правил я не знаю, я окончила Полиграфический (редакторское), а Людмила - университет, а это две очень большие разницы. Потому только она и объяснила: "Финали -н(ий) и -шн(ий) используются в относительных прилагательных с временным и пространственным значением, а..." и т. д.

Comment: Я вас предупреждал? Русским языком?

Comment: @Galina Avanesova, я уже поставил перед модераторами вопрос о нежелательности подобного на ресурсе. Поскольку Вы плохо понимаете русский язык, повторю еще раз. **Прекратите коверкать ники.** Во-первых я с вами свиней не пас, а во-вторых, это всегда рассматривалось в сети как проявление пошлости и хамства.

Comment: Об остальном готов поговорить после вашего перевоспитания.