# Смолоть/помолоть кофе

Tags: грамотная-речь, приставка

Есть ли какой-то смысловой различительный нюанс между вариантами в следующих выражениях?

- ***смолотый/помолотый*** кофе
- Я ***смолол/помолол*** кофе.

Или варианты абсолютно тождественны и можно выбирать то, что больше нравится по звучанию?

Comment: И ещё я буду благодарен, если кто-то подскажет, как правильно оформить, чтобы получился вопрос к первой фразе, т. е. фактически концу "списка".

Comment: А, ну конечно. Вопросительное предложение напрашивается на знак вопроса в конце. Но - ДИЗАЙН! Пункты столбиком да со своими горошинами мешают знаку... А в строчку выглядело бы так: "Есть ли какой-то смысловой различительный нюанс между: *смолотый/помолотый* кофе? Я *смолол/помолол* кофе?"  Два вопросительных предложения можно объединить, но в комменте со шрифтами и кавычками тяжко... Не уверена в прописном "Я" как второй части вопроса.

Comment: Спасибо, Галина! Подумаю, поменять что-то или нет.

Comment: Кстати, Галина, Вы тут упомянули, что предлог перед "концом" из моего первого комментария надо повторить (к концу). А как мне узнать общее правило на этот счёт?

Comment: Тёмочка, а задай вопрос! )))

Comment: Что-то не хочется.) Мне кажется, я сам понял ответ: моими начальными словами нормально не напишешь, а надо поменять, как, например, я сделал.

Comment: Так интересно же выкручиваться с тем, что изначально, а не переписывать. Может, так: "Есть ли какой-то смысловой различительный нюанс между: *смолотый/помолотый* кофе; я *смолол/помолол* кофе?"

Comment: Наверно, так тоже неплохо. Но мне уже больше нравится, как я сделал в итоге.) Я другой вопрос задам, если Вы мне тут не поможете.  В комментарии к behemothus-у предпоследнее предложение, где "как раз чтобы". Как там быть с запятой? Спасибо заранее!)

Comment: Опусы, пассажи и прочие интерлюдии означенного "-у" я больше не читаю, на них никак не отзываюсь. Погасли свечи после  http://rus.stackexchange.com/questions/419866/%D0%9A%D0%B0%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%B5-%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B2%D0%B8%D0%BB%D0%BE-%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B3%D1%83%D0%BB%D0%B8%D1%80%D1%83%D0%B5%D1%82-%D1%88%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B9-%D1%88%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%B9-%D0%B2-%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%BD%D1%86%D0%B5-%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B8%D0%BB%D0%B0%D0%B3%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%BD%D1%8B%D1%85

Comment: С "как раз чтобы" всё в абсолютном порядке.

Comment: А Розенталь со мной не согласился, не-а. Говорит: *§ 116. Если перед простым подчинительным союзом стоят усилительно-ограничительные слова (частицы, союзы или их сочетания, вводные слова) особенно, даже, в частности, в том числе, 
в особенности, а именно, а также, а (но) только, как раз, лишь, исключительно, только и др., то запятая ставится перед ними, а не перед союзом...*

Comment: Наверно, надо поверить Розенталю. Хотя мне бы хотелось, чтобы правильно было без запятой в этих случаях. Мне искренне жаль, что у вас такие отношения.(( Надеюсь не навсегда. Любой конфликт сильно портит жизнь, и не только самим конфликтующим.( Я бы прислушался к его словам и не злил его. Все по-разному воспринимают одно и то же.

Comment: 2. Навсегда. Для меня просто не существует более этот наукообразно-велеречивый и жеманно-жантильно-многословный неграмотный начётчик. 1. У Розенталя в примерах не совсем "наш" случай. Чую я, что ни спереди, ни сзади не надобно запятухи.

Comment: Так спереди там и негде её ставить-то!

Comment: Вот-вот. А Р. просит спереди. Внутри-то ея точно не надоть.

Comment: Oops, я окончательно запутался! Спереди, это что, вначале? Я имел в виду конец. Внутри того, что я в кавычки взял, конечно, поставить её было бы полным бредом!)

Comment: *Если перед подчинительным союзом стоят усилительные частицы как раз, только, лишь, исключительно и т. п., то запятая ставится перед ними вопреки интонации (при чтении пауза перед ними не делается)...*

Comment: Раз вопреки, значит, наверно, это всё-таки **"наш" случай**. Хотя, повторюсь, я бы рад был противоположному правилу, как вроде и Вы.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Смолотый и помолотый - и применительно к кофе, и вообще - у меня вызывают ощущение языкового дискомфорта. Согласен, что все эти новообразования совершенно не нужны, когда есть *молотый* - отглагольное прилагательное, которое закрывает все смысловые потребности. Если же очень нужно именно причастие (по какой-то авторской прихоти), то выбирать надо по смыслу исходного глагола, это ниже.

В отношении пары смолол/помолол - тут разница в результативности действия (не путать с грамматической завершенностью). Смолол - это результат достигнут, доведен до конца. Либо в понимании "весь кофе стал молотым", либо стал именно молотым, а не частично молотым (недомолотым). У приставки "С" другой семантики в данном случае быть не может.

Вот в отношении "помолол" - тут варианты. Можно понимать как не доведенное до конца действие (помолол немного и бросил), либо как синоним "смолол" - в современном языке приставка "по" несет несколько двойственную, если не тройственную, смысловую нагрузку, сравните: *побил, поел, почитал* - насколько разный понятийный смысл у приставки "по" в плане результата.

Так что "смолол" тут представляется более оправданным, если речь идет об обычной ситуации, когда смысл высказывания - в превращении кофе в состояние молотого.

Comment: Спасибо, behemothus! Мне всё в Вашем ответе нравится кроме начала. Всё-таки мне кажется, что приставки С и ПО придают характер только что (совсем недавно) сделанного действия в данном случае. "Молотый" может быть и пять лет назад помолот, а "смолотый" никак не воспримешь как несвежего помола. Может это только я так воспринимаю, не знаю. В общем, я использую это слово с этими приставками как раз чтобы придать смысл "свежести" действия (не могу найти слов, чтобы хорошо сформулировать). Принял бы ответ, если бы не начало.

Comment: ))) В русском языке нет приставок, придающих значения недавно законченного действия. Их просто не может быть, поскольку это категория грамматическая (в отличие от семантической результативности), а в русском языке нет такой видовременной формы в принципе. В тех языках, где она есть (сербский, например), её передает один из видов аориста. Собственно, аорист и в общей грамматике понимается как форма недавно законченного действия (наряду со многими другими функциями аориста). Когда-то он существовал и в русском, но конечно не с помощью приставок реализовывался.

Comment: Ого, у Вас право менять комментарий через любое время, круто! Спасибо, очень интересно это, что Вы написали! Ничего не остаётся, как поверить и принять ответ.))) Надеюсь, Галина не обидится.

Comment: Нету у меня этого права. Я просто удалил старый авриант, когда не успел исправить опечатку.

Comment: А-а, понятно!))

Comment: Зато у вас есть право менять принятый ответ. ))) Я такого не знал ранее. Но, честно говоря, я не в восторге от этого. Дело не в том, что кто-то там обидится, просто не стоит оно того. ))) Принимать надо тот ответ, который Вас устраивает, безотносительно к тому, сколько еще правильных и хороших будет после. Это на будущее.

Comment: Редко бывает, что на 100% устраивает. Вот и принимаешь какой-то обычно, п. ч. плохо оставлять без принятого. Только когда совсем не устраивают все ответы. Примешь какой-то, а тут бац и получаешь ответ, от которого в восторге!) Как тогда быть?

Answer (score 1):

Вот интересно: *[смолотый](http://www.gramota.ru/slovari/dic/?lop=x&bts=x&zar=x&ag=x&ab=x&sin=x&lv=x&az=x&pe=x&word=%D1%81%D0%BC%D0%BE%D0%BB%D0%BE%D1%82%D1%8B%D0%B9)* и *помолотый* идут как синонимы, но у *[смолотого](http://dic.academic.ru/dic.nsf/es/144397/%D1%81%D0%BC%D0%BE%D0%BB%D0%BE%D1%82%D1%8B%D0%B9)* помета "разг."... О_о

То есть нетути смыслового нюансу, а есть стилистический.

А с парочкой *смолол/помолол* - другое. Смолол - это всё, предназначенное к измельчению, или потребное количество, а помолол - это немножко как бы помолол-помолол да и притомился... Не закончил процедуру, кароч.

---

Вопрос в комменте о *к первой фразе, т. е. фактически концу "списка"* недопоняла, но там крохотная, малюсенькая такая ошибочка: перед *фактически* предлог *к* должен быть повторён.

Comment: Спасибо, Галина! "Есть ли нюанс..." — это вопрос, и заканчивается он фразой под вторым пунктом. И если я поставлю вопросительный знак в конце неё вместо точки, получится, будто это предложение вопросительное. Вот проблема и в том, где ж его поставить.

Comment: Значит, мне правильно интуиция подсказывает, что я говорю: "Всё, смолол кофе". Подчёркиваю этим, что именно закончил.

Comment: Смолол - да, свободен до пятницы! ))) Про знаки щас буду думать, надеюсь, что... смолю.

Comment: *а помолол - это немножко как бы помолол-помолол да и притомился* - это слишком однобокое представление. Может, когда-то, где-то и в каких-то случаях оно так и воспринималось, но сейчас приставка "по" вполне может нести смысл результативности: *побил, поцеловал, пожал*... Смысл частичности уходит, оставаясь только у некоторых глаголов с ярко выраженной продолженностью действия в бепристовочном варианте : читать, писать, ходить (*не в шахматах, там "ходить" - это однократное действие, "походить" - как раз сделать ход*). Вопрос только в том, насколько это актуально для глагола молоть.

Comment: По вашей ссылке помета "разг" тольлько в энциклопедическом словаре. Довольно странно брать его за основу, если ни орфоэпические словари эту помету не дают. Вот Кузнецов дает, но это опять же словарь толковый, а Кузнецов оригинал известный.

Answer (score 1):

Натуральный кофе бывает в двух основных консистенциях: в зёрнах и *молотый* (прилагательное). Упомянутые в вопросе причастия (как и глаголы) относятся к *действиям* над кофе.

"**Смолоть**" - результативное действие; подходит к ситуации с конкретной порцией зёрен, которую **всю** смололи, либо к случаю, когда кофе "*смололи в порошок*" - предельная степень действия.

"**Помолоть**" означает, что кофе какое-то время мололи, но не исключено, что не до конца - недостаточно мелко или не весь, что нужно было.

"**Смолотый**" - причастие сов. вида пр. вр. от глагола "смолоть" (имевшийся зерновой кофе, который весь смололи).

"**Помолотый**" - кофе, который мололи, например, если в кулинарном рецепте в качеcтве стадии приготовления блюда предлагалось намолоть сколько-то кофе, то далее этим словом можно сослаться на кофе, подвергнутый помолу.

```
Тот кофе, что ты мне оставила, я смолол. Смолотый кофе отдал бабушке для торта.

Сначала я помолол кофе, потом перешёл на другой конвейер фасовать уже помолотый кофе.
```

Comment: "Недостаточно мелко", конечно, сложно отнести к кофе.)) По крайней мере в случае хорошей неножевой кофемолки, где два отделения: для зёрен и для уже смолотого кофе.

Comment: Можно, вполне. Но это не главное значение, вот в чем дело. См. мой ответ и комментарий к Galina Avanesova

Comment: Спасибо, Александр! Не уверен, что правильно понял: в объяснении про "помолотый" акцент у Вас на самом порошке, а не на самой что ли "порции" или массе смолотого кофе, да?

Comment: Для меня здесь акцент на том, что этот кофе мололи совсем недавно  (отвлечённо от количества и степени помола), это ссылка на кофе, о манипуляциях с которым уже говорилось.

Answer (score 0):

Кофе обычно бывает **молотый**. Т. е. без приставки.

Comment: Автор не хочет молотого, он задаётся необычным вопросом. Ему интересны нюансы.

Comment: Приставка обычно придаёт тот смысл, что он смолот недавно.